# Android import android.nfc not resolved in eclipse

Tags: android, nfc

I have been developing this app for a month and has been doing it quite well until yesterday when everything changed and my classes involving nfc are flocking errors. as shown below:

```
 import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
 import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
 import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
 import android.nfc.Tag;
 import android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic;
 import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
 import android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable;
```

android.nfc is underlined in red!!

Comment: I did nit change my build target

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you changed your build target to be something below API Level 9:

- In Android Studio, your `compileSdkVersion` in your `build.gradle` needs to be 9 or higher
- In Eclipse, your build target in Project > Properties > Android needs to be 9 or higher

Comment: I change and the error now migrtates to "The import android.widget.PopupMenu cannot be resolved"

Comment: @KingsM: [`android.widget.PopupMenu` was added in API Level 11](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html), so you need to adjust your build target accordingly.